# Is there an Eclipse RCP equivalent of GWT Cell Widgets?

Tags: gwt, user-interface, widget, swt, eclipse-rcp

I'm looking into using Eclipse RCP on a new application where some widgets will be expected to handle large datasets.  For instance, lists with ~100k elements.  I would like to use something similar to [GWT CellList](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList) where the data will be progressively loaded as the user scrolls. Does anyone know of similar widgets available from within an Eclipse RCP environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use TableViewer with `SWT.VIRTUAL` bit set and `ILazyContentProvider`. See [this snippet](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.jface.snippets/Eclipse%20JFace%20Snippets/org/eclipse/jface/snippets/viewers/Snippet030VirtualLazyTableViewer.java?view=markup).